# Hardware back button does not bring me back to previous page

Tags: java, android, xml, hardware

I have 2 xml pages, from the main page after clicking the next button it goes to the second page, but when I press on the hardware back button. It does not goes back to the main page.

How do I add the code for the hardware back button?

Testing on Android 4.3.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Page" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Go to Page 1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java class :

```
    package com.example.linktestfyp;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1 clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: handle back button with `onBackPressed()`, you don't change the activity , you just change the layout so you must save state in one value to check that in back press.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't start a new activity when going to the 'second page'? If your second page is a different activity, Android will handle the back button.

Answer (score 1):

to navigate between activities you should call `startActivity(intent);` and not changing the `contentView` of the Same activity.
you should create two activities : Activity1(which will display the `main.xml` layout) and Activity2(which will display the `main1.xml` layout) , and while the user is in the Activity2 and press the back button , the Activity1 will be shown again **automatically** by the system, and the Activity2 will be destroyed.
Example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

see this tutorial about [how to switch between activities](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/117/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android/) with a demo sample application which you can download at the end of the tutorial .

**NB: don't forget to declare your activities in the Manifest file.**

Answer (score 0):

This may help you ..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
    //do your stuff
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: What about `OnBackPressed()`?

Comment: yeaa ... u can use that to , here is a small example of using onback pressed method ......                                                         public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Really Exit?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                WelcomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
}

Comment: but that is not ur question , u asked something like my back button doesn't bring me back , so the above answer helps you to handle the situation..

Comment: I'm not the OP, What is the difference between `OnBackPressed` and your code?

Comment: bro...both are used for same purpose ,based on the requirement.

Comment: My question is What is the difference between calling OnBackPressed and using your lengthy code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want two activities (see below). When you click on the button of `MainActivity`, the `MainActivity1` will start and display the `R.layou.main1` layout. If you click the back button, the `MainActivity1` will destroy, and the `MainActivity` will resume (by default, so you don't need to program this)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
           }

    }

}


public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing activities so when you back press the 1st page is not shown to you,

you should use setcontentview in onbackpressed() method,

then you will be able to show the 1st page otherwise it will always go to the previous activity which is not what you are looking for it seems.